# Coldfusion: Is there a way to add a break in the middle of a table? For instance, for the user to add a comment?

Tags: database, html-table, coldfusion

I have a basic sales quote website setup--the salesperson selects the part number, sets the quantity, and that part at the appropriate quantity and price is added to the table until the user indicates they are done adding parts.

So for instance on the quote that is generated, there is a table with 5 columns, with the headings Part #, Description, Qty, List Price, and Final Price respectively. From another page, the salesman looks up or enters the part info and then click "Add Part" and each part is added in consecutive rows to this table as they go automatically.

[image: Screen shot 1]

[view full image](http://midwest-microscopy.com/table.png)

What they want to do is sort the parts/group them based on category. They would like to be able to add a Category heading to the table as they add parts. So if these parts all belong to the "Red Category" they want to be able to add a line before the parts where they can type in "Red Category", keep adding parts as normal, and then when they get to a new category repeat the same.

[image: Screen shot 2]

[view full image](http://midwest-microscopy.com/category.png)

The problem I'm having is that I just have the one table, and for part they add to this table is appears all the fields need to be filled in. My first thought was to have them add a part that only had the description field filled in, but this is not working. I think it is because each part added has a certain percentage of the price automatically added to it to generate the final price column value. And then again at the end, a discount can be applied to the entire quote, which may again be causing the problem.

So more specifically I suppose my question is, is it possible to find a way for them to add a "Part" with only the description field required so they can just use that to define their category headings? Or is there a way I can actually add a break in a table like this for them to insert a category heading?

The main issue is figuring out how I can let the sales people add it when they want to. The way its set up now, the only way to add anything within the table is as a part and that part must at least have a part#, a price, and a quantity of at least one to show. My thought was that because the only way I know to add anything to this table is as a part, I could create a part that would have the part number, quantity, and price hidden when used. The sales people are able to edit the parts before added, so I thought these could serve as category headings.

I don't need it to be a category per se because each of the sales people will decide what their categories are--ad hoc basically--i have this editable part that is set not to display the quantity, price, or part number that they can call whatever they want and this will just be the category.

I'm not trying to create a category setup--I apologize--basically just and ad hoc line as a part where they can type in whatever they want but they specified to me the purpose would be to categorize their quote--we won't be saving parts in categories.

Here's the code of the table:

```
</p><cfif #Quote.ItemDiscount# EQ 0>
<table style="width:90%;margin:0 auto;font-size:11px;font-family: 'Arial';" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="Header">
                <tr>
                <td style="font-weight:bold ;border-bottom:1px solid #000;text-align:left;width:14%">Item #</td>
                                <td style="font-weight:bold ;border-bottom:1px solid #000;text-align:left;width:45%">Description</td>
                                <td style="font-weight:bold ;border-bottom:1px solid #000;text-align:center;width:9%">Quantity</td>
                                <td style="font-weight:bold ;border-bottom:1px solid #000;text-align:right;width:16%">List Price</td>
                                <td style="font-weight:bold ;border-bottom:1px solid #000;text-align:right;width:16%">Ext. Price</td>
</tr>
</table>
<cfelse>
<table style="width:90%;margin:0 auto;font-size:11px;font-family: 'Arial';" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="Header">
<tr>

                                <td style="text-align:left;width:14%"></td>
                                <td style="text-align:left;width:45%"></td>
                                <td style="text-align:center;width:9%"></td>
                                <td style="text-align:right;width:16%"></td>
                                <td style="text-align:right;width:16%"></td>
</tr>
</table>
<br>
</cfif>
<br />
<cfset #SubPrice# = 0>
<cfset #ModulePrice# = 0>
<cfif #Quote.ItemDiscount# EQ 0>
<form action="" method="post" name="QuoteSoFar"><cfloop query="Quote">
  <cfif #Quote.PartNumber# NEQ "SUBTOTAL"><table style="width:90%;margin:0 auto;font-size:11px;font-family: 'Arial';" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="Quote">
  <tr><cfif #Quote.Quantity# NEQ 0>
    <td width="14%" align="left"><font size="-1"><cfoutput>#Quote.PartNumber#</cfoutput></font></td>
    <td width="45%" align="left"><cfoutput>#Quote.Description#</cfoutput></td>

    <td width="9%" align="center"><cfoutput>#Quote.Quantity#</cfoutput></td>

    <td width="16%" align="right"><cfoutput>#DollarFormat(Quote.Price)#</cfoutput></td>
    <td width="16%" align="right"><div align="right"><cfoutput>#DollarFormat(Quote.ExtPrice)#</cfoutput></div></td>
    <cfset #SubPrice# = #SubPrice# + #Quote.ExtPrice#>
  </cfif></tr>
  <tr></tr><!---</cfif>--->

  </table>
  <cfelseif #Quote.PartNumber# EQ "SUBTOTAL"><table style="width:90%;margin:0 auto;font-size:11px;font-family: 'Arial';" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="Quote">
  <tr>
    <td width="14%" align="left"><strong><font size="-1"></font>&nbsp;</strong></td>
    <td width="15%" align="left"><strong><font color="#FF0000" size="-1">Module Price</font></strong></td>
    <td width="33%" align="left"><strong><cfoutput>#DollarFormat(Evaluate(SubPrice-ModulePrice))#</cfoutput></strong></font></strong></div></td>
    <td width="12%" align="right"><strong><font color="##FF0000" size="+1">Subtotal</font></strong></td>
    <td width="8%" align="center"></td>
    <td width="12%" align="right"><strong><font color="##FF0000" size="+1"><cfoutput>#DollarFormat(SubPrice)#</cfoutput></font></strong></div></td>
  </tr>
    <tr><cfset #ModulePrice# = #SubPrice#>
  </tr></cfif></cfloop>
  </table>
  <cfelse>
  </form><form action="" method="post" name="QuoteSoFar"><cfloop query="Quote">
    <table table style="width:90%;margin:0 auto;font-size:11px;font-family: 'Arial';" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><cfif #Quote.PartNumber# NEQ "SUBTOTAL">
  <tr><cfif #Quote.Quantity# NEQ 0>
    <td width="14%" align="left"><strong><font size="-1"><cfoutput>#Quote.PartNumber#</cfoutput></font></strong></td>
    <td width="45%" align="left"><cfoutput>#Quote.Description#</cfoutput></td>
    <td width="9%" align="center"><cfoutput>#Quote.Quantity#</cfoutput></td>
    <td width="12%" align="right"><cfoutput>#DollarFormat(Quote.Price)#</cfoutput></td>
    <cfif #Quote.ItemDiscount# LT 1>
    <td width="8%" align="right"><cfoutput>#Evaluate(Quote.Itemdiscount * 100)#</cfoutput></td>
    <cfelse>
    <td width="8%" align="right"><cfoutput>#Evaluate(Quote.Itemdiscount * 1)#</cfoutput></td>
    </cfif>
    <td width="12%" align="right"><div align="right"><cfoutput>#DollarFormat(Quote.ExtPrice)#</cfoutput></div></td>
    <cfset #SubPrice# = #SubPrice# + #Quote.ExtPrice#>
  </cfif></tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="7" align="left">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr><!---</cfif>--->
  <cfelseif #Quote.PartNumber# EQ "SUBTOTAL">
  <tr>
    <td width="14%" align="left"><strong><font size="-1"></font>&nbsp;</strong></td>
    <td width="15%" align="left"><strong><font color="#FF0000" size="-1">Module Price</font></strong></td>
    <td width="33%" align="left"><strong><cfoutput>#DollarFormat(Evaluate(SubPrice-ModulePrice))#</cfoutput></strong></font></strong></div></td>
    <td width="12%" align="right"><strong><font color="##FF0000" size="+1">Subtotal</font></strong></td>
    <td width="8%" align="center"></td>
    <td width="12%" align="right"><strong><font color="##FF0000" size="+1"><cfoutput>#DollarFormat(SubPrice)#</cfoutput></font></strong></div></td>
  </tr>
    <tr><cfset #ModulePrice# = #SubPrice#>
    <td colspan="7" align="left">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</cfif></table></cfloop><!---</cfif>--->
</cfif>
</form>
<cfif #QuoteTrack.Discount# NEQ 0>

<table style="width:90%;margin:0 auto;font-size:11px;font-family: 'Arial'; border-bottom: 1px solid #000; border-top: 1px solid #000;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                        <tr>
<br>
                            <td style="text-align:left;font-weight:bold;">Subtotal:</td>
                            <td style="text-align:right;font-weight:bold;"><cfoutput query="Totals"><strong>#DollarFormat (Totals.Expr1000)#</strong></cfoutput></td>
                            </tr>
                            <cfset #Cost# = #Totals.Expr1000#>
                            <tr>
                            <td style="text-align:left;font-weight:bold;">Less Discount(%):</td>
                            <td style="text-align:right;font-weight:bold;"><cfoutput><strong>#Evaluate (QuoteTrack.Discount*100)#</strong>%</cfoutput></td>
                            </tr>
                            <cfset #Inverse# = (1-#QuoteTrack.Discount#)>
                            <tr>
                            <td style="text-align:left;font-weight:bold;">&nbsp;</td>
                            <td style="text-align:right;font-weight:bold;">&nbsp;</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                            <td style="text-align:left;font-weight:bold;">Total:</td>
                            <td style="text-align:right;font-weight:bold;"><cfoutput>#DollarFormat (Evaluate(Cost * Inverse))#</cfoutput></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>

                        <cfelse>

<table width="30%" border="0" align="center">
  <tr>
    <td align="right"><strong><font color="#FF0000" size="+2">Total</font></strong></td>
    <td align="right"><cfoutput query="Totals"><strong><font color="##FF0000" size="+2">#DollarFormat (Totals.Expr1000)#</font></strong></cfoutput></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</cfif>
<br />
```

Comment: I have read this several times and still do not understand the actual issue ;-) In order to help, we first need to see some code. Also, as you seem to be describing a client side form, it would help to include a screen shot as well.

Comment: **I** have _also_ read this several times and still do not understand the actual issue ;-) In order to help, we first **NEED TO SEE SOME CODE**. Also, as you seem to be describing a client side form, **IT WOULD HELP TO INCLUDE A SCREEN SHOT** as well.

Comment: Ok; I apologize guys; I've edited again.

Comment: Yet we still don't see any **CODE**. The answer to your question is yes but that doesn't really help you much does it. If you can share some code we can start to help you out more.

Comment: I've added the code for the table

Comment: Everyone I'm really sorry for the noobish way I posted and very much appreciate the guidance. Thank you!

Comment: I keep reading and re-reading your question but just can't get my head around your problem. I added the screen shots to be visible with your question and tried formatting your code. Wow! One comment, you do not need to enclose the ColdFusion variables within hashtags inside of `<cfif>` and `<cfset>` tags. Instead of this `<cfset #SubPrice# = 0>` you can do this `<cfset SubPrice = 0>` and instead of this `<cfif #Quote.PartNumber# NEQ "SUBTOTAL">` you can do this `<cfif Quote.PartNumber NEQ "SUBTOTAL">`. This is not your problem but I believe it makes the code even harder to read.

Comment: Another thing I am noticing from your code is that it appears as though you are not correctly nesting some of your `<cfloop>` tags within your `<cfif>` tags. I see a `<cfloop>` beginning within a `<cfif>` tag but the closing `</cfloop>` tag is outside of the `<cfif>` statement? Obviously this is not complete source but that problem will throw an error. It could be a mistake on my part. I am still trying to go through your code example. I tried to format it along with the pictures but could not because of the missing tags/structure. I'm still trying...

Comment: Thank you for the code advice; I need to know those little details! I did a little more looking at this last night and of course in the description field I can format the text with html/css to be larger, italicizes and moved to the right so it appears as though this is a heading RATHER than a part. However, the system will not allow me to add a "part" to the table if I don't add a value for the other fields--that was my original thought--give them a part with part number 0 and they can just edit the description to say whatever they want--and somehow make it so the part # doesn't display

Comment: --I'd have to figure out how to basically make it so no fields display but the description. I can just set all the prices to $0 and the quantity to 1 so it shows--that won't impact their totals, but I can't figure out how to make it so those other fields don't display.

Comment: Are you just asking how to display the categories in a row without the other columns? If so, use the `colspan` attribute of the `<td>` tag. Since your table has five columns you would want to span all of them. Like this: `<td colspan="5" style="text-align:left;">Category Name Here</td>`. (I'm still having a hard time figuring out what your issue is.)

Comment: Thank you for that; the main issue is figuring out how I can let the sales people add it when they want to. The way its set up now, the only way to add anything within the table is as a part and that part must at least have a part#, a price, and a quantity of at least one to show. My thought was that because the only way I know to add anything to this table is as a part, I could create a part that would have the part number, quantity, and price hidden when used. The sales people are able to edit the parts before added, so I thought these could serve as category headings. Does this help?

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to use a part for a category. It will be like a square peg in a round hole. You will most likely run into issues/limitations in the long run. In that scenario, how will you link the parts to the category? I don't think you will be able to because the "category" is just another part. Why can't you create a new category table? Then you can design it as needed. So that you can add a true category and use database keys to link the parts to categories and vice-versa.

Comment: Is it possible to do this though? I understand what you're saying but I'm not sure I yet have the expertise to add a command to add multiple tables and then add all those prices and apply the discount. I'm not sure how multiple tables would effect this.

Comment: I'm not trying to create a category setup--I apologize--basically just and ad hoc line as a part where they can type in whatever they want but they specified to me the purpose would be to categorize their quote--we won't be saving parts in categories.

Answer (score 0):

*This is not really an answer to your question (yet) but it is too long for a comment. I will update this as more info is provided.*

I have formatted your code example in an attempt to make it easier to read. In doing so I found some tags that seem to be out of place. This may or may not be the case as the code that you provided is incomplete. I added comments within this code with my initials `MF` and a number `1`, `2`, and `3`. These indicate the places where I believe closing tags are out of place in your code.

```
<p></p>
<cfif Quote.ItemDiscount EQ 0>
    <table style="width:90%;margin:0 auto;font-size:11px;font-family: 'Arial';" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="Header">
    <tr>
        <td style="font-weight:bold ;border-bottom:1px solid #000;text-align:left;width:14%">Item #</td>
        <td style="font-weight:bold ;border-bottom:1px solid #000;text-align:left;width:45%">Description</td>
        <td style="font-weight:bold ;border-bottom:1px solid #000;text-align:center;width:9%">Quantity</td>
        <td style="font-weight:bold ;border-bottom:1px solid #000;text-align:right;width:16%">List Price</td>
        <td style="font-weight:bold ;border-bottom:1px solid #000;text-align:right;width:16%">Ext. Price</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
<cfelse>
    <table style="width:90%;margin:0 auto;font-size:11px;font-family: 'Arial';" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="Header">
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align:left;width:14%"></td>
        <td style="text-align:left;width:45%"></td>
        <td style="text-align:center;width:9%"></td>
        <td style="text-align:right;width:16%"></td>
        <td style="text-align:right;width:16%"></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
</cfif>
<br />
<cfset SubPrice = 0>
<cfset ModulePrice = 0>
<cfif Quote.ItemDiscount EQ 0>
    <form action="" method="post" name="QuoteSoFar">
    <cfloop query="Quote">
        <cfif Quote.PartNumber NEQ "SUBTOTAL">
            <table style="width:90%;margin:0 auto;font-size:11px;font-family: 'Arial';" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="Quote">
            <tr>
            <cfif Quote.Quantity NEQ 0>
                <td width="14%" align="left"><font size="-1"><cfoutput>#Quote.PartNumber#</cfoutput></font></td>
                <td width="45%" align="left"><cfoutput>#Quote.Description#</cfoutput></td>
                <td width="9%" align="center"><cfoutput>#Quote.Quantity#</cfoutput></td>
                <td width="16%" align="right"><cfoutput>#DollarFormat(Quote.Price)#</cfoutput></td>
                <td width="16%" align="right"><div align="right"><cfoutput>#DollarFormat(Quote.ExtPrice)#</cfoutput></div></td>
                <cfset SubPrice = SubPrice + Quote.ExtPrice>
            </cfif>
            </tr>
            <tr></tr>
            <!---</cfif>--->
            </table>
        <cfelseif Quote.PartNumber EQ "SUBTOTAL">
            <table style="width:90%;margin:0 auto;font-size:11px;font-family: 'Arial';" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="Quote">
            <tr>
                <td width="14%" align="left"><strong><font size="-1"></font>&nbsp;</strong></td>
                <td width="15%" align="left"><strong><font color="#FF0000" size="-1">Module Price</font></strong></td>
                <td width="33%" align="left"><strong><cfoutput>#DollarFormat(Evaluate(SubPrice-ModulePrice))#</cfoutput></strong></font></strong></div></td>
                <td width="12%" align="right"><strong><font color="##FF0000" size="+1">Subtotal</font></strong></td>
                <td width="8%" align="center"></td>
                <td width="12%" align="right"><strong><font color="##FF0000" size="+1"><cfoutput>#DollarFormat(SubPrice)#</cfoutput></font></strong></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <cfset ModulePrice = SubPrice>
            </tr>
            <!--- MF 1 - CLOSING TABLE TAG SHOULD GO HERE --->
        </cfif>
    </cfloop>
    </table> <!--- MF 1 - SEEMS LIKE THIS SHOULD BE MOVED UP --->
    <!--- MF 2 - CLOSING FORM TAG SHOULD GO HERE --->
<cfelse>
    </form> <!--- MF 2 - SEEMS LIKE THIS SHOULD BE MOVED UP --->
    <form action="" method="post" name="QuoteSoFar">
    <cfloop query="Quote">
        <table table style="width:90%;margin:0 auto;font-size:11px;font-family: 'Arial';" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <cfif Quote.PartNumber NEQ "SUBTOTAL">
            <tr>
            <cfif Quote.Quantity NEQ 0>
                <td width="14%" align="left"><strong><font size="-1"><cfoutput>#Quote.PartNumber#</cfoutput></font></strong></td>
                <td width="45%" align="left"><cfoutput>#Quote.Description#</cfoutput></td>
                <td width="9%" align="center"><cfoutput>#Quote.Quantity#</cfoutput></td>
                <td width="12%" align="right"><cfoutput>#DollarFormat(Quote.Price)#</cfoutput></td>
                <cfif Quote.ItemDiscount LT 1>
                    <td width="8%" align="right"><cfoutput>#Evaluate(Quote.Itemdiscount * 100)#</cfoutput></td>
                <cfelse>
                    <td width="8%" align="right"><cfoutput>#Evaluate(Quote.Itemdiscount * 1)#</cfoutput></td>
                </cfif>
                <td width="12%" align="right"><div align="right"><cfoutput>#DollarFormat(Quote.ExtPrice)#</cfoutput></div></td>
                <cfset SubPrice = SubPrice + Quote.ExtPrice>
            </cfif>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td colspan="7" align="left">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        <!---</cfif>--->
        <cfelseif Quote.PartNumber EQ "SUBTOTAL">
            <tr>
                <td width="14%" align="left"><strong><font size="-1"></font>&nbsp;</strong></td>
                <td width="15%" align="left"><strong><font color="#FF0000" size="-1">Module Price</font></strong></td>
                <td width="33%" align="left"><strong><cfoutput>#DollarFormat(Evaluate(SubPrice-ModulePrice))#</cfoutput></strong></font></strong></div></td>
                <td width="12%" align="right"><strong><font color="##FF0000" size="+1">Subtotal</font></strong></td>
                <td width="8%" align="center"></td>
                <td width="12%" align="right"><strong><font color="##FF0000" size="+1"><cfoutput>#DollarFormat(SubPrice)#</cfoutput></font></strong></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <cfset ModulePrice = SubPrice>
                <td colspan="7" align="left">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        </cfif>
        </table>
    </cfloop>
    <!--- MF 3 - CLOSING FORM TAG SHOULD GO HERE --->
<!---</cfif>--->
</cfif>
</form> <!--- MF 3 - SEEMS LIKE THIS SHOULD BE MOVED UP --->
<cfif QuoteTrack.Discount NEQ 0>
    <table style="width:90%;margin:0 auto;font-size:11px;font-family: 'Arial'; border-bottom: 1px solid #000; border-top: 1px solid #000;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <br>
        <td style="text-align:left;font-weight:bold;">Subtotal:</td>
        <td style="text-align:right;font-weight:bold;"><cfoutput query="Totals"><strong>#DollarFormat (Totals.Expr1000)#</strong></cfoutput></td>
    </tr>
    <cfset Cost = Totals.Expr1000>
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align:left;font-weight:bold;">Less Discount(%):</td>
        <td style="text-align:right;font-weight:bold;"><cfoutput><strong>#Evaluate (QuoteTrack.Discount*100)#</strong>%</cfoutput></td>
    </tr>
    <cfset Inverse = (1-QuoteTrack.Discount)>
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align:left;font-weight:bold;">&nbsp;</td>
        <td style="text-align:right;font-weight:bold;">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align:left;font-weight:bold;">Total:</td>
        <td style="text-align:right;font-weight:bold;"><cfoutput>#DollarFormat (Evaluate(Cost * Inverse))#</cfoutput></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
<cfelse>
    <table width="30%" border="0" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td align="right"><strong><font color="#FF0000" size="+2">Total</font></strong></td>
        <td align="right"><cfoutput query="Totals"><strong><font color="##FF0000" size="+2">#DollarFormat (Totals.Expr1000)#</font></strong></cfoutput></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</cfif>
<br />
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll make those changes; I appreciate the insight on that; I can't believe i read it wrong as I did